# ViewPager with Headerview and Collapsible Toolbar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have to implement viewpager with headerview and Collapsible Toolbar. I have implemented that but currently scroll only works on viewpager view not on the headerview. 
Please let me know the way to fix this issue.

Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrHeader"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbarHeaderLayout" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lnrCustomProfile"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--- Header Layout--->

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/customprofileshoplayout" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dividerline"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrayBorder"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/tabsProfile" />
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@id/tabsProfile"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/black"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tabSelectColor"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/tabColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/lnrCustomProfile" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dividerline"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrayBorder"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tabsProfile" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vwpagerProfileProducts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: checkout https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/working-with-material-design-and-activity-transition/ , it may help

Comment: @Aakash : Thanks. But my concern is that, will the scroll works when I tried to do scroll on ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

your TabLayout like headerview. try [this sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare). the sample implemented viewpager and tablayout & collapsingtoolbarlayout.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I think you didn't got my question.

Comment: ohh. excuse me. but suggested you sure using https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: The sample contains the Design library, but I want headerview with viewpager.

Comment: i can not see your scrollview?

Comment: I'm using viewpager. I want to scroll viewpager and headerview together, like we are doing that with listview.